# How to select documents by checking array elements in mongodb and spring criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, criteria-api

I have the following document

```
{ "std_name": "Abcd", "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"] },
{ "std_name": "Wxyz", "tags": ["tag4", "tag1", "tag3"] },
{ "std_name": "Demoname", "tags": ["tag4", "tag2", "tag3"] },
```

where i have to select all documents with tag2
i tried with criteria as follow but returns null

1.`Criteria.where("tags").is("tag2")`

2.`Criteria.where("tags").all("tag2")`

how to get the result.

Comment: Your query looks correct. Can you show the rest of your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in function to select all document having tag2.

```
Criteria.where("tags").in(Arrays.asList("tag2"));
```